# Syntax Check (C++) in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

An incremental build can take me 10-30 seconds based on what file I am working on. It's extremely annoying to Hit F6 to do a build, see the errors I made but not be able to edit anything for the next 5-25 seconds while the build is occurring.

Is there any way I can tell Visual Studio to do a syntax check? Can I set the action to a button?

Comment: I don't want to sound smug, but for many years I used to work on a project where a full build on a single-core machine took almost an hour, with 5-10mins for linking, the rest was compilation. When you changed only one cpp file, it was still 5-10mins. But I was doing template stuff in lowly headers (string handling, error handling and the like), and having to recompile the whole thing each time was _really_ annoying until we started to compile distributed. Build times down to 12mins! It was heaven.

Answer (score 3):

You can compile individual `.cpp` files in Visual Studio. When you right-click on them in the Solution Explorer, you'll find a menu item "Compile". My Visual Studio also shows the keyboard shortcuts (it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> for my settings), but you might have to turn this on somewhere.

Comment: I actually found a button for this in MSVC9 and put it in the "build" toolbar at the top, next to "build project" and "build solution".  Unfortunately, I can't find the button for MSVC10.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I think you can create a custom button and bind it to the command.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I was able to quickly setup such a button in VS2010: Pick any toolbar (or create a new one), click on the down arrow at its very right, pick _Add Or Remove Button_, then _Customize_. In the dialog popping up Click on _Add Command_ and pick _Build_/_Compile_. Commit this by clicking on _Ok_, and you have added the _Compile_ command to the toolbar.

Comment: Fascinating.  That's the screen I've been studying, but my "Add Command" does not have a "Build/Compile".  Maybe that option is missing in the express edition, or I broke something.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Oh, Express. I wouldn't know about that.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to do this from the command-line? I only see doing a full on build of a solution/project. Thanks.

Comment: @SirPentor: You an certainly use the compiler from the command line. In a typical project, however, the command line for a compiler invocation is quiet complex. I think there's an option to make VS emit the command lines it uses to invoke the compiler in the build output. You can copy that. OTOH, MSBuild might have options to allow compilation of single `cpp` files. I don't know much about it, though.

Comment: @sbi thanks. What I really want is devenv.com or msbuild.exe, run from the command-line, given a solution and/or project file and a cpp file to do the single-file compile. I'm pretty sure that's not possible with devenv.com anyway.

Comment: @Sir: That's what `MSBuild.exe` is for. It's pretty simply to find out how to call it by using its built-in help. (`MSBuild /?`, I think.)

Answer (score 0):

In VS2008 anyway, there's a "compile" thinger in the build menu, mapped to - on my system. That just does a compile of the current file, no linking, and no dependency stuff. Probably does what you need.

Comment: I only see build (F6) there. Which does linking and such

Answer (score 0):

I usually just cancel the build (Ctrl+Break or menu Build->Cancel).

So,

1. Start build solution
2. Realize there's a trivial code syntax error or whatever, fix problem (solution is still building)
3. Ctrl+Break
4. Relaunch build solution